# Associative Rules in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I Have an array :

```
$test = array("c1","c2","c3","c4");
```

How to make assosiatif all item ? example :

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
c1c2
c1c3
c1c4
c2c3
c2c4
c3c4
c1c2c3
c1c2c4
c1c3c4
c2c3c4
```

and if i add an item in variable test, i dont add a for again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer for you.

```
 $test = array("c1","c2","c3","c4");
    for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++){
        for($j=$i+1; $j<count($test);$j++){
            echo $test[$i].','.$test[$j].'<br />';
        }
    }
```

this was true for the initial format of the question. good luck